# Bibliography brackets are empty

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

Somehow my Biblatex isnt working with alphabetical style.
[image: The result is looking like this]

Numerical style is working 
normally.
My header looks like this:

```
\usepackage[
backend=biber,
style=alphabetic,
citestyle=authoryear
]{biblatex}
%
\addbibresource{literatur/literatur.bib}
```

citing with:

```
\cite{bsi}
```

and my .bib file looking like this:

```
@online{bsi,
    ALTauthor = {Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik},
    title = {Cloud Computing Grundlagen},
    urldate = {2019-11-14},
    url = {https://www.bsi.bund.de/DE/Themen/DigitaleGesellschaft/CloudComputing/Grundlagen/Grundlagen_node.html}
}
```

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: `biblatex` generates the `alphabetic` label from the `author`/`editor`/`translator` and `year` field (it can fall back to `label` or `shorthand`). None of those fields are populated here, so `biblatex` has nothing to go by.

Comment: Try `author = {{Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik}}, shortauthor = {BSI},`. (I couldn't find a sensible year of publication on the site)

Comment: Unless you have additional options, I would not recommend the style mixture `style=alphabetic, citestyle=authoryear`. Either take `style=authoryear,` or go with `style=alphabetic`. A mixture of the two is just confusing and inconsistent.

Comment: Thanks very much. It's working now. I was assuming, that the reference name is used in the bracket.

Answer (score 2):

The standard definition for `alphabetic` labels tries to take the `labelname` field (one of `author`, `editor`, `translator`) and the `date`/`year` and combine the two into a combination along the lines of "SR98". One can use the `label` field to override the `labelname` part of the label or `shorthand` to override the complete label.

In the example entry none of the mentioned fields are filled, so `biblatex` does not manage to generate any label from the entry. It is at least possible to give the `author`, so I'd suggest something like

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{bsi,
  author      = {{Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik}},
  shortauthor = {BSI},
  title       = {Cloud Computing Grundlagen},
  url         = {https://www.bsi.bund.de/DE/Themen/DigitaleGesellschaft/CloudComputing/Grundlagen/Grundlagen_node.html},
  urldate     = {2019-11-14},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
\cite{sigfridsson,bsi}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: [BSI] Bundesamt für Sicherheit in der Informationstechnik. Cloud Computing Grundlagen. url: https://www.bsi.bund.de/DE/Themen/DigitaleGesellschaft/CloudComputing/Grundlagen/Grundlagen_node.html (besucht am 14.11.2019).]

---

The entry key (`bsi`) should be thought of as a purely internal label. None of the common standard styles will ever use the entry key in the output.